# Prior Art for US20130128968 A1?

Tags: prior-art-request, us20130128968

Please help find Prior Arts for [US20130128968 A1](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20130128968A1/en).

```
Publication number  US20130128968 A1
Publication type    Application
Application number  US 13/680,740
Publication date    May 23, 2013
Filing date         Nov 19, 2012
Priority date       Nov 17, 2011
```